# Why is this syntax wrong (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This is the code i use to send an email with a contact form:
my route:

```
 Route::post('/contatti/mail','ItemController@mail');
```

my controller

```
public function mail()

    {

$data = Input::all();
 $rules = array(
'subject' => 'required',
'message' => 'required'
 );

 $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if($validator->fails()) return Redirect::to('contatti')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();




$emailcontent = array (
 'subject' => $data['subject'],
 'emailmessage' => $data['message']
 );

 Mail::send('emails.contactmail', $emailcontent, function($message){

 $message->to('mymail@mymail','')->subject('Contatti');

return Redirect::to('contatti')->with('flash_message', 'Mail sent');
}





}
```

Why this sintax is wrong? I mean, i can't nest function in a controller in laravel?
How can i do to send the mail? I should use the post and send to a route called Mail::send with that call another controller with that parameter?

EDIT: This is the error i get:
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a syntax error 
close closure function parentheses

```
Mail::send('emails.contactmail', $emailcontent, function($message){$message->to('mymail@mymail','')->subject('Contatti'); });
```